# Selenium Standalone Servers giving error "DefaultRemoteProxy unknown version,Connect to 10.0.2.15:5566 [/10.0.2.15] failed: connect timed out"

Tags: selenium, grid

Selenium Grid Testing:

I have installed virtual box in my system and I am trying to use my local system as  hub and the windows machine in the virtual box as node.

Whatever the selenium standalone server I use ( I tried a lot of versions) but it is always giving me the error "DefaultRemoteProxy unknown version,Connect to 10.0.2.15:5566 [/10.0.2.15] failed: connect timed out" on the grid console.

In the Command Prompt initially it is saying that the node is registered successfully but after some time it is saying " Marking the node http://10.0.2.15:5566 as down: cannot reach the node for 2 tries".

I have attached the screenshot. Because of this the tests are failing.

I have disable the windows firewall as well on both local and virtual box windows systems. But still no luck.

Is there anything wrong I am doing?

Can someone please help me with this?

Selenium Grid Console:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After trying a lot, I got the answer finally. This is related to network setup between my local host and the VM.

In VMBox, under the settings for a particular system, under network I have added one more adapter which is "Host-only adapter" in addition to the NAT and it resolved my problem.